# How to put PHP 'for loop' within a single variable (for email use)?

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a 'for' loop (repeating element with dynamic content) inside a single variable, which is then used as the 'body' of an email.

I've tried using EOD - as I'm essentially echoing out text and relevant variables, but this doesn't seem to accept the 'for' loop. Forgive the PHP newbie skills. Thanks.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$body = 
for ($prod_count = 1; $prod_count <= $_SESSION['review_counter']; $prod_count++) {
...
loop over relevant incremental variables
...
};
```

...later this $body is used in something like (that why I want it as a single variable)...

```
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `foreach`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

With a simple `for` your code should look something like this below

```
for ($prod_count = 1; $prod_count <= $_SESSION['review_counter']; $prod_count++) {
    $body[$prod_count] = "something";
};
```

Comment: Won't that give me multiple $body variables appended with a number? ie: $body1, $body2 etc. I'm after a single $body variable that contains a dynamic number of a repeating element.

Comment: This would give you an array called $body where you can access every variable with $body[1], $body[2] etc

Comment: Thanks for quick response - much appreciated. I'm using this and the implode function to pull the array into a single string.

Comment: Please consider mark the answer if it helped you solving your problem. This way other users with the same issue will find it easily

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like below and return $body variable which you can send in email.

```
<code>
  function generate_body_text($prod_count) {
  $body = '';
  for($prod_count = 1; $prod_count <= $_SESSION['review_counter']; $prod_count++) {
    //your logic
  };  
  return $body;
  }

  $body = generate_body_text($prod_count);
  $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks. This function method also looks good. I've used the above method, imploding the array to a single string. (I've accepted the array method - but I don't have the experience to know if this is better or not, or for what reasons).

Comment: If there are some manipulation with body text then this is a  good approach to make your code clear with good readability. If then there is only single line string then array method is good.